# android json php example not working

Tags: php, android, json

i m new to android JSON ,i am getting problem in fetching data from my server database table.i need to show on my android page id ,name and address on settext
but i am not getting the data from server through JSON..here is my complete code:

HERE IS MY JSON FILE:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

HERE IS MY MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.my.data1.JSONParser;

 public class Tab1Activity extends Activity {

//URL to get JSON Array
   private static String url = "http://app-developments.com/Jasmita/Address-          book/Get_product_details.php";

//JSON Node Names
private static final String TAG_Address_Book = "Address_Book";
private static final String TAG_ID = "Id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
private static final String TAG_ADD = "Address";

JSONArray Address_Book = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab1);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome", 4000).show();
    // Creating new JSON Parser
   JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
     JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

     try {
        // Getting JSON Array
        Address_Book = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Address_Book);
        JSONObject c = Address_Book.getJSONObject(0);

        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        String add = c.getString(TAG_ADD);

        //Importing TextView
        final TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ID1);
        final TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name1);
        final TextView email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.add1);

        //Set JSON Data in TextView
        uid.setText(id);
        name1.setText(name);
        email1.setText(add);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception is: " +e,    4000).show();
}

}

}
```

here is my php file:

```
<?php

/*
* Following code will get single product details
* A product is identified by product id (pid)
*/



  // array for JSON response
   $response = array();


  // include db connect class
   require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect1.php';

  // connecting to db
 $db = new DB_CONNECT();

   // check for post data



    // get a product from products table
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Address_Book") or                   die(mysql_error());


             if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    $response["Address_Book"] = array();

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $Address_Book = array();
    $Address_Book["Id"] = $row["Id"];
    $Address_Book["Name"] = $row["Name"];
    $Address_Book["Address"] = $row["Address"];



    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["Address_Book"], $Address_Book);
     }
       // success            // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // echoing JSON response
      echo json_encode($response);
     } else {
      // no products found
       $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "No products found";

      // echo no users JSON
       echo json_encode($response);
         }

            ?>
```

Comment: where is your complete code?? i cant see it..!!

Comment: Are you using CURL ? why don't you post your code?

Comment: waiting for your complete code...

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in LogCat?

Comment: no ...it is not connecting to database

Comment: that could mean there is a bug in your php script. Did you confirm it is working well?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the PHP script, you can check that by just opening the url in the browser. You have, however, remove the whitespace in the URL for this to work. Is the whitespace also in your actual code, or is this a copy&paste error? If it is also in your actual code, this could be the culprit.

Comment: no it was just in copypaste itherwise my php file is working fine

Answer (score -1):

You left out a lot of information and code, but I'll still try to answer your question, based on what I think your problem is:

As far as I'm aware, your php file that serves as your GET request from the database works fine, but you aren't being able to call it on your Android.

I too had some problems with GET requests on Android when I first started, and all the classes I was supposed to use (those that were included on the tutorials), were deprecated.

I finally searched around enough and made something that worked, and saved a sample of what I did on my PasteBin. I'll share it with you how you're supposed to make a GET Request on Android, and all you have to do is apply it to your project.

```
 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String URL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    URL = "http://The-URL-To-Your-PHP-File";
    ConnectToDatabase connect = new ConnectToDatabase();
    Thread th = new Thread(connect);
    th.start();
}

  class ConnectToDatabase implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Log.d("link", URL);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(URL);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
            RESULT - DO WHATEVER WITH IT
        */
        Log.d("result", result.toString());


    }
}
```

This should work. If it doesn't, then, for the love of god, give us what the error message is.

Comment: shud i applied it on my main activity?plz clarify

Comment: as i am using eclipse

Comment: @z.al Use it on whatever activity you're executing your code on. Mine at the time was called Main2Activity, because I couldn't bother to think of a name for it. You can use it on your Main Activity just fine, for all I care.

Comment: null pointer Exception:lock==null  i m getting this exception when applying your code

Comment: @z.al That possibly means your InputStream in is null.
Could mean there's an error on your php file, or you just implemented my code wrong.

Comment: you can see my php file n i have implemented correctly just add my url

Comment: if u r having any example of data fechting from server and settext on android page thn plz share with us

Comment: @z.al The PHP file itself seems fine, I think the problem right now might be in the "db_connect1.php" or your "db_config.php" file. There's nothing you can do on Android if your php file doesn't work. Try to open your php file on a browser. Does it give out any errors? If so, could you copy paste them back to me?

Comment: its not giving any error and showing the data from the database...its in android only which gives null value....i dont know y

Comment: @z.al are you using a localhost? WAMP/XAMPP,etc? Android usually won't be able to connect to it if you're using an emulator, unless you do something specific. If you're using your own phone to debug the apk and using a localhost, you also need to do something, but different from the emulator one. I think it has to do with the IP.
Also, did you add the "INTERNET" permission to your manifest? Without it, your android app doesn't have permission to access the internet. 
If you need me to explain myself further it's no problem, just ask all the basic stuff and I'll guide you through it c:

Comment: no i have file on server (actual) and  i have added internet permission also;(

Comment: i have previously done this type of example but with listview n by selecting id i got the data to settxt to my android page but this time i want it directly without selecting id ..i need to show the data from my server to my android page by just clicking thre button

Comment: @z.al wait... did you change the `public static String URL` to your URL? I guess I should have specified, but that variable Can't be empty x) you have to assign the url of the file you're trying to reach. That could be why it's showing null value for the input reader.

Comment: no thts fine url is the same...still m nt getting any value (

Comment: @z.al Is there any way you can paste your code on Pastebin? Make different pastes for all your activities, so I can look at your code in it's entirety c:

Comment: i havent used pastebin